# Does feature scaling always make mean zero?

Tags: multidimensional-scaling, feature-scaling

I came across a dataset which scaled the data and gave mean, closer to zero, not exactly zero.
Any insights how does scaling work ? I read that it gives mean zero and variance 1.

I tried using sklearn.preprocessing.scale and sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how it’s normalized. If it’s just a linear transform that maps the minimum value to -1 and the maximum value to 1 (like MinMaxScaler does), then the mean is not necessarily going to be zero.

But that’s not common in machine learning. It’s more common to normalize by [standardization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score#Standardizing_in_mathematical_statistics), which explicitly shifts the data to have mean 0 and variance 1.